# Need help in trying to read text file with no spaces to 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to read a file with no spaces to an array. I have to input the file name, open the file, turn it into a 2D array, then print it out to a txt it later after editing it. The array looks like this, although its number of rows and columns can change (with a max of 10x26):

```
...A..B..C..
..ABC...AB..
```

And so on and so forth. What I've tried is:

```
string fileName;
   cout << "Enter the name of the input file: ";
   cin >> fileName;
   ifstream Scanner;
   Scanner.open(fileName);
   int fileArray[10][26];
   for(int rows = 0; rows < 10; rows++)
   {
      for(int seats = 0; seats < 26; seats++)
      {
         Scanner >> fileArray[rows][seats];
      }
   }

   for(int r = 0; r < 2; r++)
   {
      for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    {
        cout << fileArray[r][c];
    }
   }
```

However, when I try to print the array it gives a bunch of numbers, not the characters I tried to place into it. Any help would be appreciated. All i need is to get over this hurdle of putting the text file into a 2D array and then I think I can finish off the program.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is indeed a *bunch of numbers* because you declared it so.

`int fileArray[10][26];` this should be `char fileArray[10][26]`

OR

you could cast while printing like so

`std::cout << static_cast<char>(fileArray[r][j])`

Comment: Thanks so much, thats exactly what was wrong- now I just need a way to change the size of the array to fit the file :)